# Virsh guests lose network connectivity

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm, virsh

A CentOS 7 host installs CentOS 7 virtual machines inside itself using a `virt-install` command, which includes an assigned MAC address.  The CentOS 7 host is connected via Ethernet to a hardware firewall/router, which has assigned a static IP address to the MAC address that is given to a specified virtual machine.  Machines elsewhere in the same network are able to communicate with the virtual machine when it is installed (`ping`, `telnet`, etc.).  However, several days later, the virtual machine is not able to send or receive communications with the rest of the network (no `ping`, no `telnet`, etc.)  This problem is resolved when the virtual machine is destroyed, and then the same `virt-install` command is used to re-install a clone of the virtual machine.  This indicates that the connectivity unreliability problem is caused by something INSIDE the virtual machine.

**What specifically can be done in order to cause these virtual machines to be able to maintain reliable, lasting connectivity with the rest of the network?**

---

**The Code:**

---

The virtual machines are created by running the following `virt-install` command on the host:

```
virt-install --name=first-centos7 --disk path=/tmp/firstDisk.qcow2,size=241  
--graphics none --vcpus=1 --memory=3072 --location /tmp/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso  
--network bridge=br0 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0  
--mac=52:54:00:ma:ca:dr --initrd-inject=/tmp/vm.ks --extra-args "ks=file:/vm.ks console=ttyS0"
```

Should this `virt-install` command be changed?  Or should some command inside the resulting virtual machine be changed?  Or does something in the host need to be changed in order to enforce reliability for all the guest virtual machines?

Comment: Are you sure that br0 is running? Try 'virsh net-list --all'

Comment: @bitofagoob I just re-installed the virtual machines, as described in the OP.  Therefore, I cannot do a valid test of what you suggest.  However, I did imagine that there might be some command to check/ensure that the required elements are persistent.

Comment: If you have the console enabled/configured on the system, did you checked if the VM is responsive from the console (virsh console <vm-name>) when is not reachable through the network?

Comment: @DarkVex Yes, when the virtual machine was not reachable through the network, I typed `virsh console vm-name` from the host.  I was able to get into the virtual machine's command line in that way.  And from inside, I ran `ping other.ips.on.network` and got a similar error message indicating that the network was not reachable.

Comment: And when pings from the VM and to the VM were failing, did you try to run tcpdump at the bridge, the host's interface and the tap device, to see where exactly they were failing? Also, instead of reinstalling the VM did you try to reboot it, and if that didn't restore connectivity, stop/start it?

Comment: @dyasny Thank you.  I did not try the things that you suggest. However, your comments here are creating a list of things that I can try when this next occurs. I really appreciate that because we cannot keep deleting virtual machines.

Comment: I agree with @dyasny another thing that you can check is if the VM still have an IP assigned. If I have undestood properly the VM is in DHCP and you have done an IP reservation on the firewall/router